# Mean speed in a network

Tags: statistics, means, simulation

I am new to this community so I hope this is the rigth place for this question.
I am working on traffic simulations on a certain area, and I need to know which is the average speed in the area during the simulated period (4 hours). I know, for each vehicle in the simulation, the distance covered and the time needed, thus I can compute the mean speed of each vehicle by dividing those two.
Now that I have a list of mean speeds, what is the more correct thing to do: should I compute the average of those mean speeds, or their harmonic average? And why one is more suitable than the other? By searching online I found out that harmonic average is commonly used to compute the mean speed of a vehicle, but does this apply also to multiple vehicles on multiple different streets?
Second question: I will do multiple simulations with different parameters, and at the end I need to know the mean speed over the N simulations. Can I simply compute the mean (or harmonic mean?) of the mean values obtained in each simulation?
I hope I have been clear enough.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: "more correct" is subjective, it all comes down to what you want out of the measure.  The harmonic mean has the nice property that it gives you the constant velocity which would yield the same amount of travel time, which is one reason people looking at rates often use it.  See, for instance, [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23117/which-mean-to-use-and-when)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would add up all the distances travelled and all the times travelling, then divide the first by the second.

- If each time was the same, this would amount to the arithmetic mean of the individual speeds
- If each distance was the same, this would amount to the harmonic mean of the individual speeds
- If distances and times both vary, this would give a different figure and in my view a better one

You can then compare these overall results between different simulations; the total distances and total times in  different simulations may also be interesting information.